# Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $an + 1$ s a cube if and only if $ bn + 1$ is a cube. Prove that $a = b.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers such that $an + 1$ is a cube if and only if $bn + 1$ is a cube. Prove that $a = b.$

By choosing $p_n^3 \equiv 1 \mod b$ , we find that there are infinitely many numbers $n$ such that $:bn+1=p_n^3\Rightarrow an+1=q_n^3$

So we have : $(a-b)n = q_n^3-p_n^3 \Rightarrow (a-b)$ is a divisor of an infinite number of numbers $T$ of the form$:T=p^3-q^3$

This is a quite hard problem for me. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: If you see some other unusual quality question, consider bringing it up in [the Pearl Dive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive) also.

Comment: What is wrong with the answers already received so far?

Comment: @Mike The existing answers are also eligible for the bounty. Sorry about not making that clear. I just had  a hunch that may be something else is out there. And this question is, in my opinion, worthy of a bit more exposure, which is one of the prime goals of the Pearl Dive project.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more detailed plan. The first hint was indeed unclear.

- It follows from the conditions that for all positive integers $m$ the number $an+1$, where $n=\frac{(bm+1)^3-1}{b}$ is a perfect cube.
  In other words, for every $m$ the number $ab^2m^3+3abm^2+3ma+1$ is a cube of positive integer.
- Define a polynomial $p(x)=ab^2x^3+3abx^2+3ax+1$. We know that $p(x)$ is a perfect cube if $x$ is a positive integer. Our goal is to prove that $p(x)=(rx+s)^3$ for some integers $r$ and $s$.
- We will show a more general fact: suppose that a polynomial $p$ of degree $d$ with integer coefficients is a perfect $d$-th degree whenwver $x$ is a positive integer. Then, $p(x)$ equals $(rx+s)^d$ for some positive integers $r$ and $s$.
- We will suppose that the leading coefficient of $p$ is $\alpha>0$. Then, it is clear that for some $M>0$ and all sufficiently large $n$ we have inequalities
  $$
  (\alpha^{1/d}n-M)^d<p(n)<(\alpha^{1/d}n+M)^d.
  $$
  On the other hand, for each $n$ we have $p(n)=k_n^d$ for some positive integer $k_n$. Thus, $k_n\in(\alpha^{1/d}n-M,\alpha^{1/d}n+M)$ for all sufficiently large $n$.
- The next step is to show that $k_n-\alpha^{1/d}n$ has a finite limit $\beta$ when $n\to\infty$. It follows from the existence of limit
  $$
  \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p(n)-\alpha n^d}{n^{d-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{k_n^d-\alpha n^d}{n^{d-1}}.
  $$
- Now we have $k_n=\alpha^{1/d}n+\beta+o(1)$, when $n\to\infty$. However, if $\alpha^{1/d}$ is not an integer, then it is irrational. Hence, due to the Kronecker Theorem, there exist infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $(\alpha^{1/d}n+\beta-1/3,\alpha^{1/d}n+\beta+1/3)$ does not contain integers which contradicts to the fact that $k_n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
- Now we know that $\alpha^{1/d}$ is an integer, so is $\alpha^{1/d}n$. It follows that $\beta\in\mathbb{Z}$ and, moreover, $k_n=\alpha^{1/d}n+\beta$ for all large $n$.
- Since $p(n)=k_n^d=(\alpha^{1/d}n+\beta)^d$ for large $n$ we must have $p(x)=(\alpha^{1/d}x+\beta)^d$ as desired.
- Now return to the problem. We have
  $$
  (rx+s)^3=ab^2x^3+3abx^2+3ax+1.
  $$
  Comparison of coefficients yields that $a=b$.

Comment: You mean $" ab^2m^3+3abm^2+3ma+1 "?$

Comment: Can you help me with the rest, I've been thinking about it and can't solve it. Sorry

Comment: I'm not able to follow either.

Comment: @yoursmileeeeee Yes, it was a typo. I edited my answer and added more details.

Comment: Niven's liitle book Diophantine Approximations says Kronecker's Theorem is: when $\alpha, \beta$  are irrational and $1, \alpha, \beta$  linearly independent over rationals, the points $(n \alpha, n \beta)$  mod the standard integer lattice are dense.

Comment: @WillJagy By Kronecker's Theorem here I meant that fractional parts $\{n\theta\}$ are dense in $[0,1]$ when $\theta$ is irrational, i.e. $\{n\theta+m\colon n,m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: alright. He says the version in the line goes back to Weyl, Sierpinski, and someone named Bohl, while the planar version is Kronecker. He does not give specific citations, recommends 1936 book by Koksma for that.

Comment: @Mike where is it necessary to use that $ab^2$ is not a cube? I’m failing to see where that is on the proof.

Comment: @Jacob maybe I was a bit hasty. I do see now that the case where $ab^2$ is a cube is covered. But to answer your question as my thought process, for there to be no integers in the interval $(\alpha^{1/3}+\beta-1/3, \alpha^{1/3}+\beta+1/3)$, we require $\alpha^{1/3} to be non-integral.

Comment: @Mike $\alpha^{1/3}$ is assumed to be irrational for the purpose of proof by contradiction.

Comment: @Jacob ...which would require $ab^2=\alpha$ not being a perfect cube

Answer (score 3):

Here's a fairly short proof.

There are infinitely many positive integers $n$ for which $abn+1$ is a cube $x^3$ (any $x\equiv 1\pmod{ab}$ works). Then, $a^2n+1$ and $b^2n+1$ must both be cubes; say $a^2n+1=y^3$ and $b^2n+1=z^3$. We have
$$(y^3-1)(z^3-1)=(a^2n)(b^2n)=(abn)^2=(x^3-1)^2;$$
rearranging gives
$$y^3+z^3-2x^3=(yz)^3-x^6.$$
If $x^2=yz$, then $y^3+z^3=2x^3$, and so $(a^2+b^2)n=2abn$ and $a=b$. So, if $a\neq b$, $x^2\neq yz$, which means
$$\left|y^3+z^3-2x^3\right|=\left|(yz)^3-x^6\right|\geq\min_{t\in\mathbb Z_{\neq 0}}\left|(x^2-t)^3-x^6\right|=3x^4-3x^2+1.$$
If $y^3+z^3\leq 2x^3$, then $|y^3+z^3-2x^3|<2x^3$, which contradicts the above inequality for $x>1$. So $y^3+z^3>2x^3$, and
$$\max(y^3,z^3)\geq \frac{y^3+z^3}2\geq x^3+\frac{3x^4-3x^2+1}2\geq x^4+1.$$
Let $z\geq y$, so that $z^3-1\geq x^4$. Then $b^2n\geq (abn+1)^{4/3}$, which can't hold for large $n$.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the answer above by @richrow, the crux is showing that, if $a \not =b$, there is an integer $M$ such that $ab^2M^3+3abM^2+3aM+1$ is not a perfect cube. Note also that we may also assume that $a<b$. We give an alternative proof of this, that does not use the Kronecker Theorem.

**Case 1: $ab^2$ is not a perfect cube.** To this end first let $M_1,M_2,M_3\ldots$ be an infinite sequence of positive integers satisfying $\phi(M_k)$ **not divisible by** $3$ **for each** $k$, where $\phi(\cdot)$ is the Euler totient function; each $M_k$ a product of the first $k$ primes $p_1,p_2$ where each $p_i =2\pmod 3$ will do--or even simpler $M_k =2^k$ for each integer $k$ will work. Then that $3$ does not divide $\phi(M_k)$ implies the following:

> For each $k$: If an integer $c$ satisfies $c^3 \equiv_1 M_k$, then $c \equiv_1 M_k$.

Thus, for each $k$, let us write $f(M_k)=ab^2M_k^3+3abM_k^2+3aM_k$. Then the following holds:

> Claim 1: For each $k=1,2,\ldots$, if $f(M_k)$ is a perfect cube, then $f(M_k)$ must then be of the form $f(M_k) = (c_kM+1)^3$ for some integer $c_k$.

Furthermore, as $ab^2$ is integral and not a perfect cube, iy follows that the inequality $|c^3_k -ab^2| \ge 1$ holds. Also clearly $c_k \le ab^2+3ab+3a+1$ $=O(1)$.

Then suppose that each $f(M_k)$ is a perfect cube. Then by Claim 1, $f(M_k)=(c_kM_k+1)^3$ for each integer $k$. So on the one hand, the following is true:
$$f(M_k)-c^3_kM^3_k$$ $$= 3c^2_kM^2_k + 3c_kM_k +1$$
$$= O(M_k^2) \quad  \forall k=1,2, \ldots.$$ However,  the inequality $|ab^2-c^3_k| \ge 1$ holds for all $k$. So on the other hand, the following is also true:
$$|f(M_k)-c^3_kM^3_k| \ge M^3_k\pm O(M^2_k)$$ $$=\theta(M^3_k) \quad \forall k=1,2,3,\ldots.$$ Now as both of the above cannot be simultaneously true for an infinite number of $k$ however, so we arrive at a contradiction. So it follows that $f(M_k)$ can be a perfect cube for only finitely many of the $M_k$s, and thus there exists a $k$ such that $f(M_k)$ is not a perfect cube for the case where $ab^2$ is not a perfect cube. So the result follows if $a$ and $b$ satisfy Case 1.

**Case 2: $ab^2$ is a perfect cube.** Then assume $a<b$ and so writing $ab^2=c^3$, it follows that $c<b$ and so $3ab=3c^3/b <3c^2$, and similarly $3a < 3c$. So then for each integer $M$:
$$c^3M^3 < ab^2M^3 + 3abM^2+3aM+1$$  $$ < c^3M^3+3c^2M^2+3cM+1 = (cM+1)^3.$$
So here $ab^2M^3+3abM^2+3aM+1$ cannot be a perfect cube in the case where $ab^2$ is a perfect cube, so the result follows if $a$ and $b$ satisfy Case 2 as well.

Comment: For Case 1 you could set this up so that in fact the strict inequality $c^3_k <ab^2$ is guaranteed to hold. First, as in Case 2 assume $a<b$ which gives, for all $3ab < 3c^2$ and $3a< 3c$ for all integral $c$ satisfying $c^3 > ab^2$. Then this guarantees that $(cM_k+1)^3 >  ab^2M^3_k +3abM_k^2+3aM_k+1$ [strict inequality] for any $c$ satisfying $c^3 \ge ab^2$. Thus, $c^3_k <ab^2 \Rightarrow c^3_k \le ab^2-1$.